# Entity Framework return a value (null) before the request return from the database

Tags: c#, multithreading, entity-framework

My database is simple : I have Contracts, Customers and Areas. Each Contract is associated to exactly one Customer and each Customer is associated to exactly one Area. Thus :

```
Contract.Customer.Area.AreaId
```

should *always* be valid since neither Area nor Customer can be null.

Now, the following code is executed **in a worker thread** (and it uses the `ObjectContext` created in the main thread - I know, this is not a good idea, but I'm doing code maintenance) :

```
if (something)
   CallA();
else if (Contract.Customer.Area.AreaId == (int)Area.Worldwide)
   CallB();
```

Surprisingly, when these lines are executed, `Contract.Customer.Area` is null ***most*** of the time (and the third line causes a crash).

Using EF Profiler, I see that Entity Framework send a request to the database (to read the Area object) just before the crash happens. But it doesn't seem to wait for the response...

Also : if I place a breakpoint on the `if` and step through the lines with F10, `Contract.Customer.Area` is always valid. Same thing when it crashes : if I move the PC to the `if` and hit F10, `Contract.Customer.Area` is valid too.

Any ideas why Area is null? And how should I correct this ? Using Include to pre-load the Areas seems to work... for now.

Thanks!

Comment: (personal experience)Most of the time when I ever get a null value and I really don't know why, it had something to do with threads.
But in your case I'm not sure, because I don't know your code.

Comment: Can you post please the Customer and the Area classes

Comment: @BassamAlugili They are Entity Framework generated classes. They are generated from an EDMX file. The context inherit from ObjectContext. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I assume you activated **lazy-loading** without explicit loading of related entities, so both `Contract.Customer` and `Contract.Customer.Area` are only fetched from DB when you access to them. This explains why the debugger *always* shows a valid value (the debugger itself causes a SQL request to be executed as you try to evaluate those properties).

As for your crash with NRE, one can guess the context has been disposed so lazy-loading doesn't work anymore (even if I would expect `ObjectDisposedException` instead of NRE).

How to fix? Explicitly load your entities. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx

Comment: Yes, it's using lazy-loading. However, the context is created at startup and kept in a static variable. It is not disposed since I can load another contract after the crash. Thanks for the link!